# Pick image from Android phone and store it in mobile application

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I need to store fitness client pictures to my application (Android). I'm doing my app in Compose and I have my own server (Ktor with MySQL).

Code: This is code for XML

```
  private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            binding.imageView.setImageURI(data?.data)
        }
    }
```

Do u know in which format should I put it in database (varchar, int or something else) ?
Case: Client send me some pictures i want to upload it to specific client, how to store it in database on server ?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Android as your server with database is not Android.

Comment: And if you want to upload to your server then what is it that you want to upload to specific client?

Comment: I want to upload pictures but I dont know in which format picture is (when imported) and which field should I put in database so that when I login next time picture will be shown properly

Comment: Why do you need to know the format? Whatever that would be.. And you did not answer about that client.

Comment: I dont know how to store it in db, should it be a string or int? Im not sure

Comment: Well that question has nothing to do with Android. You can store an image-file in a blob.

Comment: Personally I think images should be stored on the filesystem and not in a db

Comment: But path could be saved into db.

Comment: @Equlo Don't think in terms of paths.  You're getting a content URI from the picker.  That may be a file, but it may not be.  And you may not have read access to that URI in the future.

Comment: Hmm, do u have some hint or library how to store it in db so that next time i can connect let say string from my server db and uri to show specific picture